# ARM template to configure the backup configuration

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

**Updated**

I need to write an ARM template to configure the Automatic backup to occur once per day and the retention period would be 48 hrs.

Once It's configured then I need to verify either my backup is getting created or not.
Please help me to know where exactly need to check the backup file in the azure portal?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Have you tried creating a resource in portal and exporting the template for example?

Comment: I have not tried anything, Please share with me if you any reference to start?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal#export-template-from-a-resource

Comment: The above link mostly to download the existing template, what I am looking at regards cosmos DB backup configuration which we can do from the Azure portal

Answer (score 2):

Below an example setting the interval to one day (1440 minutes). I've set the retention to two days as you'll get two backups for free.

```json
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
  "apiVersion": "2020-06-01-preview",
  "name": "MyCosmosDatabase",
  "location": "West Europe",
  "kind": "GlobalDocumentDB",
  "properties": {
    //other properties
    "createMode": "Default",
    "backupPolicy": {
      "type": "Periodic",
      "periodicModeProperties": {
        "backupIntervalInMinutes": 1440,
        "backupRetentionIntervalInHours": 48
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I use this Release pipeline to configure it?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. You can definately deploy an ARM template from a pipeline although that's totally unrelated to the question. Also I'm not tech support

Comment: I tried the template and found it's successfully deployed, but I am not sure how to check it in the portal?

Comment: In the `Backup and Restore` blade under the `Settings` section

Comment: Thanks, Yes, it's showing the backup interval and retention period, and where we can see the backup file?

Comment: You can't. The only way to have it restored is by contacting Microsoft. You can create a ticket through Azure Portal for that